# User SSRS usage statistics report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

Using SQL Server 2008, I have a SSRS report. Users can view this report on Sharepoint.
I need to get user usage staticks for this report (like Number of Visits).

Which ways I can do it? Hope for you help.

Comment: This was asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179082/tracking-report-usage

Comment: Didn't find it before, thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT c.Name,
       e.Timestart,
       e.TimeEnd,
       e.UserName,
       e.Status,
       c.Description,
       e.InstanceName,
       e.ReportID,
       e.TimeDataRetrieval,
       e.TimeProcessing,
       e.TimeRendering,
       e.Source
  FROM <yourSQLdatabase.dbo.ExecutionLog e
INNER JOIN <yourSQLdatabase>.dbo.Catalog c
    ON e.ReportID = c.ItemID
 where timestart >=  @startdate
   and timestart <=  @enddate;
```

is what I use to get report statistics.  If you just need a count you can do a group by the c.name field with a count(*).  The user calling the report is in e.userName; this includes scheduled reports which will come up with a name like "NETWORK SERVICE".

Comment: Oops; didn't notice that there was a link above pointing to a prior solution; that link gives additional useful information beyond what I've posted above.